# Orientdb list databses read timeout

Tags: console, orientdb

The error happen when i try to list the db's in my system. I use the orientdb console : "list databases" command

com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStrorageException: Cannot retreive the configuration list.

Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the wrong section of the prompt (i.e, i was actually connected to a db, in order to list the db's you have to be out of this db).